# Docker Pull Access Denied for Repository does not exist or login required

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, dockerfile

I want to place the existing web api inside the docker container. I added the Docker file through visual studio.

The application build is successful. But when I try to run the docker. It doesn't provide any information.

The docker repository is created

[image]

when i run the below cmd it executes and doesn't throw any error

[image]

The IOswagger is my application image.

When I run the image without the tag. The command automatically takes the tag of another image and it throws an error saying the repository doesn't exists.

[image]

In the docker the image is running.
[image]

Docker FIle :

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-nanoserver-1903 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-nanoserver-1903 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["aspnetcore-server/src/IO.Swagger/IO.Swagger.csproj", "aspnetcore-server/src/IO.Swagger/"]


RUN dotnet restore "aspnetcore-server/src/IO.Swagger/IO.Swagger.csproj"
COPY . .

WORKDIR "/src/aspnetcore-server/src/IO.Swagger"
RUN dotnet build "IO.Swagger.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "IO.Swagger.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "IO.Swagger.dll"]
```

When I try to build the application using docker it fails. The build is failed by throwing "Command failed with exit code 1"

I don't know how to proceed further. Not sure whether my application is even running or not.

Comment: You miss the `:dev` tag. `docker run -p 8080:80 ioswagger:dev`, and you must stop/remove any previous container running on port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late and not exactly the case what you described, but I have faced with the same error when specified in Dockerfile wrong link to docker image like

`FROM microsoft-dotnet-aspnet:5.0 AS base`

when it should be:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
or 
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
```